# Setting Data() with object

Tags: jquery

For some reason I couldnt get it to work.

This is the syntax I used:

```
li = $("<li>")
.addClass("user-online-now")
.data({'userid': data.userID,'ts': dataTS, 'domain': data.domain})
.html(a);
```

But it would not set the data tags, no matter what I tried.

So I ended up using `attr`:

```
li = $("<li>")
.addClass("user-online-now")
.attr({'data-userid': data.userID,'data-ts': dataTS, 'data-domain': data.domain})
.html(a);
```

Which worked.  It bugs me that I can't use `data()` because it would be cleaner code.  Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Using jQuery 2.2.2

Comment: This is expected behaviour. `data()` updates jQuery's internal cache, not the DOM. So long as you use `data()` as both a getter ***and*** setter, it works absolutely fine - and performs better than `attr()` too

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan So just because I can't see it on the element doesnt mean that it's not there?

Comment: That's correct. If you use `data()` to get the value - eg. `console.log($('li.user-online-now').data('userid'))` - you should see the value returned

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan You're right.  Thank you.  If you want to put it as an answer I'll mark it correct.

Comment: That's ok, the question has already been marked as a duplicate so no answers can be added.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
var li = '<a  href="#" class="user-online-now"'+
          'data-userid="1" data-ts="ts" data-domain="domain">Hello</>'

$('div').html(li);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div></div>
```

you can set data **attr** like this.

Comment: OP already knows this - it was his attempted solution. He is asking *why* he needs to do it.